# How can I use bash substitution for date inside a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I do something like :

```
bat """
    echo $(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
"""
```

What I tried :

- escape the $ with backslash
- escape the % with backslash
- double the %

Also Jenkins BUILD_ID variable has been removed so that's why I'm trying other options.

As mentioned in the docs BUILD_ID is defunct and I'm looking for a drop-in replacement for this variable.

> BUILD_ID The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59"
> (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss, defunct since version 1.597

Source https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

See also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26520

In this last link, I found that piece of code to add to "prepare env" but don't know how to use it without plugin EnvInject (no plugin can be installed by the way)

```
return [BUILD_TIMESTAMP:currentBuild.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")]
```

Comment: You have `bat`, not bash nor sh. Windows Batch script is different from bash. `Also Jenkins BUILD_ID variable has been removed` ?? It's still in documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/ , how do you know it's removed?

Comment: @KamilCuk - they're trying to use syntax highlighting for batch, but `echo $(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)` is very much a bash command.

Comment: BUILD_ID

The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss, defunct since version 1.597) https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Comment: I know it's bat, not bash. I should be able to take advantage of the MINGW64 environment. It comes with git bash which is also available in cmd.

Comment: @SomethingDark I'm curious where you see anything about syntax highlighting here.

Comment: @Sybuser the `bat """` on the first line of your code. What else would it be?

Comment: @SomethingDark No the characters used for syntax highlighting for stackoverflow are 3 backquotes ```. The 3 double quotes here indicate the start of script for the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Well it's still wrong since the code inside of the quotes is bash.

Comment: No, there's a command date.exe in MINGW64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues here:

- date.exe from Windows clashes with date.exe from MINGW64
- bash substitution with $(...) will not work in bat

A solution using Powershell:

```
bat """
for /f %%i in ('powershell get-date -format "{yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}"') do set datetime=%%i
echo %datetime%
"""
```

With the date command from Git-Bash :

```
for /f %%i in ('C:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin\date.exe +%%Y%%m%%d_%%H%%M%%S') do set dt=%%i
echo %dt%
```